# Using ActionMailer and Mandrill API to send to multiple recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mandrill

I am trying to get my app to send notification emails to all admins when certain actions are executed. Everything works fine if I have only one admin, but I keep getting an error when there is more than one admin. I'm using rolify gem to give users admin roles, and Mandrill to send out emails. In my Mandrill dash, I am getting successful API calls when this executes, but when I test it via console, I get an error.

In my mailer file:

```
def new_ticket_created ticket

    to = User.with_role(:administrator).map{|user| user.email}.uniq.join ','
    mail to: to, subject: "New ticket created!"
  end
```

The error I get in the console:

```
ProjectMailer#new_ticket_created: processed outbound mail in 418.7ms
[{"email"=>"admin_user@validemail.com, admin_user2@validemail.com", "status"=>"invalid", "reject_reason"=>nil}]
```

I have a successful status when I only have 1 user marked as admin, and I get the intended email in my inbox. Not sure why I can't get it to send to multiple recipients, it seems to be formatting the addresses correctly.